# Is it possible to interpolate a template string using data from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, template-strings

Is it possible to interpolate a template string using `key/value`s from a object in JavaScript, like string substitution in Python:

```
data = {"age": 18, "name": "John"}
"I'm %(name)s. I'm %(age)d years old" % data       # "I'm John. I'm 18 years old"
```

One way that I can think of is using the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement,

```
let data = {age: 18, name: "John"}
with(data){`I'm ${name}. I'm ${age} years old`}
```

but `with` is highly not recommended, it is neither efficient nor safe.

Is there a better way?

Comment: ````I'm ${data.name}s. I'm ${data.age}d years old````

Comment: Using `I'm ${data.name}. I'm ${data.age} years old` is a valid option? Another way could use object  deconstruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can destruct data object:

```js
let data = {age: 18, name: "John"}
function with({name,age}){ return `I'm ${name}. I'm ${age} years old`; }
```

or do this:

```js
let data = {age: 18, name: "John"}
function with(data){return `I'm ${data.name}. I'm ${data.age} years old`;}
```

Comment: `with` is a keyword, which makes your code syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @InSync I just learnt this keyword and what it does, and figured why the code in question didn't make sense to me at first. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is a major difference between Python's `string substitution` and JavsScript's `template string`.

- The template string in Python is exactly a `string`, it is only substituted when `%` is called,
- while the template string in JS is substituted at the time it is declared and evaluated.

So, the answer could be different in different scenarios:

If I simply want to interpolate a template string with a specific object named `data`, I can simply use

```
`I'm ${data.name}. I'm ${data.age} years old`
```

If I want to declare a template string, and interpolate it using different objects, I can use a function:

```
(_=>`I'm ${_.name}. I'm ${_.age} years old`)(data1)    // `data1` can also be `data2` or `person3`
```

If I want to have some more elegent template strings, and make it somewhat programmable, I can use a [tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates):

```
function interpolate(strings, ...keys){
    return function(obj){
        let i
        let result=""
        for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            result+=strings[i]+obj[keys[i]]
        }
        return result+strings[i]
    }
}
// or an inline version, some difference in `undefined` value handling:
interpolate=(strings,...keys)=>(obj=>new Array(keys.length*2+1).fill().map((_,i)=>i&1?obj[keys[i>>1]]:strings[i>>1]).join(""))
// usage
interpolate`I'm ${"name"}. I'm ${"age"} years old.`(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this
`I'm ${data.name}. I'm ${data.age} years old`
You should use this inside backticks (``).